# how to retrieve HTML form fields in JavaFX application

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>WebView</title>    
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
   <input type="text" name="tb1" id="ib1">
   <button id="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>

package webviewsample;

public class WebViewSample extends Application {

    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {      
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(), 750, 500, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);   
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
class Browser extends Region {

    private HBox toolBar;
    private static String[] imageFiles = new String[]{
        "help.png"
    };
    private static String[] captions = new String[]{
        "Help"
    };
    private static String[] urls = new String[]{
        WebViewSample.class.getResource("help.html").toExternalForm()
    };
    final ImageView selectedImage = new ImageView();
    final Hyperlink[] hpls = new Hyperlink[captions.length];
    final Image[] images = new Image[imageFiles.length];
    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    final Button showPrevDoc = new Button("Toggle Previous Docs");
    final WebView smallView = new WebView();
    final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
    private boolean needDocumentationButton = false;

    public Browser() {
        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");

        for (int i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
            // create hyperlinks
            Hyperlink hpl = hpls[i] = new Hyperlink(captions[i]);
            Image image = images[i] =
                    new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageFiles[i]));
            hpl.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
            final String url = urls[i];
            final boolean addButton = (hpl.getText().equals("Documentation"));

            // process event 
            hpl.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    needDocumentationButton = addButton;
                    webEngine.load(url);
                }
            });
        }

        webEngine.setOnAlert((WebEvent<String> event) -> {
        System.out.println("ALERT!!!! " + event.getData());

        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(event.getData());

        alert.showAndWait();

        JSObject jso = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
        jso.setMember("bridge", new Bridge());

    });

        comboBox.setPrefWidth(60);

        // create the toolbar
        toolBar = new HBox();
        toolBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        toolBar.getStyleClass().add("browser-toolbar");
        toolBar.getChildren().add(comboBox);
        toolBar.getChildren().addAll(hpls);
        toolBar.getChildren().add(createSpacer());

        //set action for the button
        showPrevDoc.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event t) {
                webEngine.executeScript("toggleDisplay('PrevRel')");
            }           
        });

        smallView.setPrefSize(120, 80);

        //handle popup windows
        webEngine.setCreatePopupHandler(
            new Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine>() {
                @Override public WebEngine call(PopupFeatures config) {
                    smallView.setFontScale(0.8);
                    if (!toolBar.getChildren().contains(smallView)) {
                        toolBar.getChildren().add(smallView);
                    }
                    return smallView.getEngine();
                }
             }
        );        


        //process history
        final WebHistory history = webEngine.getHistory();
        history.getEntries().addListener(new 
            ListChangeListener<WebHistory.Entry>(){
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Change<? extends Entry> c) {
                    c.next();
                    for (Entry e : c.getRemoved()) {
                        comboBox.getItems().remove(e.getUrl());
                    }
                    for (Entry e : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        comboBox.getItems().add(e.getUrl());
                    }
                }
        });

        //set the behavior for the history combobox               
        comboBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent ev) {
                int offset =
                        comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()
                        - history.getCurrentIndex();
                history.go(offset);
            }
        });



        // process page loading
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov,
                    State oldState, State newState) {
                    toolBar.getChildren().remove(showPrevDoc);    
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            JSObject win = 
                                (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                            win.setMember("app", new JavaApp());
                            if (needDocumentationButton) {
                                toolBar.getChildren().add(showPrevDoc);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        // load the home page        
        webEngine.load("http://www.oracle.com/products/index.html");

        //add components
        getChildren().add(toolBar);
        getChildren().add(browser);
    }

    // JavaScript interface object
    public class JavaApp {

        public void exit() {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }

    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        double tbHeight = toolBar.prefHeight(w);
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h-tbHeight,0,HPos.CENTER,VPos.CENTER);
        layoutInArea(toolBar,0,h-tbHeight,w,tbHeight,0,HPos.CENTER,VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 600;
    }
}
```

I will render this HTML page in JavaFX application, I will enter something in textbox and hit submit button. I want to get entered textbox value inside JavaFX application. Can some one please tell me how can I achieve this?

I want entered textbox value inside my Java class. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
index.html
<fieldset>
    <legend>LoginForm</legend>
    USERNAME: <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname">
    PASSWORD: <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <button onclick="app.submit(document.getElementById('uname').value)">Submit</button>
</fieldset>

public class JavaApp {

        public void submit(String userName) {
            System.out.println("Inside exist application method");          
            System.out.println("userName-->"+userName);
            //Platform.exit();
        }
    }

JSObject win = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                win.setMember("app", new JavaApp());
```

I did like this and able to have the textfield value inside my Java Class, Can some one please let me know is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with webengine but looking into the docs reveals the following snippet which could be a starting point

```
EventListener listener = new EventListener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event ev) {
        Platform.exit();
    }
};

Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
Element el = doc.getElementById("exit-app");
((EventTarget) el).addEventListener("click", listener, false);
```

So you could try to attach a handler to your submit button and then lookup your disired field to get the text.

Comment: In addition to this, you should monitor the state property of the web engine load worker so that you only get the document once it has been loaded, otherwise the document will be null.  Information on this is in the [WebEngine javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html).